# C# 7.1 and default feature

Tags: c#

I just discover the possibility to use "default" with C# 7.1.

Here is the story. I like to use the initializers when I create a new object because it force me to work properly. I can use the Ctrl-Space shortkey to use the intelisense and the list of available properties I must initialize decrease.

```
                var order = new Order
                {
                    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    // DeleteDate = I dont want to set the delete date so I comment it
                    SupplierClientCode = GetClientCode(),
                    Version = 1,
                };
```

The problem is when I don't want to initialize my property I need to comment the line. Then I lose the possibility to remove all properties and to easily check I didn't forgot to initialize something.

Later I found the possibility to use the default() feature like this:

```
                var order = new Order
                {
                    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    DeleteDate = default(DateTime?), // Better
                    SupplierClientCode = GetClientCode(),
                    Version = 1,
                };
```

And recently I just discover that I can simply write default

```
                var order = new Order
                {
                    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    DeleteDate = default, // Great
                    SupplierClientCode = GetClientCode(),
                    Version = 1,
                };
```

But to be able to use this my Visual Studio ask me to update the version to 7.1.

[image]

First I checked my properties because I'm already using 4.7.2 (so 7.2 from my understanding).

[image]

So I'm curious and I clicked on yes, let's do it go for 7.1. What is it? And I discovered this in my project file:

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
    <LangVersion>7.1</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

What is this tag `<LangVersion>7.1</LangVersion>`?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/langversion-compiler-option

Answer (score 1):

The [`<LangVersion>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/langversion-compiler-option) tag is used to designate which version of your language should be supported by the compiler (in this case C#). By setting it to 7.1, it'll allow you to use features that were introduced in that version of the language such as default literals, pattern matching, etc.

If you want to take full advantage of all new language features, you could consider setting this to `latest` which would use the latest available version of the language:

```
<LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
```

It's worth noting that there are constraints based on the versions of Visual Studio, MSBuild, and the SDK your application is targeting that dictate which features you can/cannot use:

[image]

Comment: But why is it not enough to use the default Target framework?

Comment: This could depend on a variety of things such as the version of the SDK you have installed, the version of Visual Studio,etc. If you attempt to use these features without having the appropriate versions required by the chart in my response, Visual Studio will _upgrade_ your project for you and pull in the necessary dependecies to take advantage of the language features (i.e. add the `<LangVersion>` section to your config and likely a DLL that contains support for the language features you requested something like `Microsoft.Net.Compilers` if memory serves).

Answer (score 1):

There are two different concepts here:

- The .NET Framework is basically a set of features which can be used, if your project is a .NET Framework project. The other options are .NET Core and .NET Standard. The newest version of the .NET Framework is 4.8.
- The C# language version. This often depends on your version Visual Studio (if you are using that). The newest language version is C# 8.

Comment: I though is was tight together. At the moment i target my 4.7.2 .NET framework by default the system understand I will use C# 7.1.

Comment: @BastienVandamme they are often indirectly tied together by Visual Studio, since that comes with a default version of each.